# Is it theoretically possible to control an continuously flexible inverted pendulum?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, nonlinear-control

We can control an inverted pendulum relatively easily with PID.

We can control a double-inverted pendulum with more sophisticated methods.

Lately, a triple inverted pendulum was controlled, [with 56 transition states mapped](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5GvwWKkBmg&t=466s).

So, how far can this go? Is there a mathematical limit to this? Is it possible to control an 'infinite' pendulum given the numbers are crunched? Although I doubt this will ever happen in reality since the pendulum effectively becomes a chain, I'm interested in the limits of the theory.

Comment: Many "more sophisticated methods" can be made using multiple of the components of a "PID" - it's a matter of what you call an input or output.  If you are limited only to the land of theory, then any system that can be theoretically modeled can be theoretically controlled within the theoretical limits within which it can be controlled- it isn't a matter of it but a matter of how much.  For example if I limit the theoretical output of a system to 0 to 1, I can't theoretically command it to 2 and get it there.

Comment: `effectively becomes a string` ... not exactly ... the motion iof the pendulum s constrained to only one plane

Comment: I one is interested only in regions *in the neighborhood* of equilibrium, then the problem can be linearised and the linearised system can be checked for [observability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability) and [controllability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability).

Comment: I saw your "infinite inverted pendulum" in the title and took it to mean an infinitely long, single-pivot pendulum.  The proper term for what you're looking for is probably an "infinite-state" inverted pendulum; a "continuously flexible" inverted pendulum may be even better, but less intuitive.  Please _edit your question_ to clarify.  I'm pretty sure that a chain that is infinitely flexible in any direction perpendicular to the chain's local "length" but perfectly stiff along it's local center axis will be uncontrollable -- but I have a memory that you can control a flexible, springy strip.

Comment: For a general assemblage of linkages, no. The accelerations and velocities needed at the base grow faster than linearly. But oddly, there should be a particular arrangement of links that let you drive the base with harmonic motion and the the whole thing should stay upright. It's like a LaGrange point in three body systems - it's locally stable.